# Json file replaces the data instead of adding

Tags: php, json

I have a Json file which i'm using for my website, however when I fill out the form and send it over to my Json file it somehow replaces the old data with the new one instead of adding it with an increment.

my json/php set-up:

```
 $id = '';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 if(file_exists('json_files/database.json')) {
        $current_data = file_get_contents('json_files/database.json');
        $array_data = json_decode($current_data, true);
        $last_item = end($array_data);
        $last_item_id = $last_item['id'];
        $arrExercise = array(
            'id' => ++$last_item_id,
            'exerciseTitle' => $Title,
            'exerciseWord' => $question_takeAudio_exerciseWord,
            'syllables' => $Syllables
            );
         $array_data[] = $extra;
         $final_data = json_encode($array_data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
            if(file_put_contents('json_files/database.json', $final_data)) {
                  header("Location: exercise_CMS.php");
        } else {
             echo "Oopsie! Something went wrong!";
             exit();
       }
   }
}
```

my json:

```
{
"id": 1,
"exerciseTitle": "Huisss",
"exerciseWord": [
    "Huisarts"
],
"syllables": [
    "Huis",
    "arts"
]
}
```

now, if I would fill out my form again, the above would be REPLACED for the new data send over to my json file. I want it however, to add it underneath with the increment of +1. Am I missing out on something?
EDIT: the json/php set-up has been updated. but most likely I am still missing parts out because now it returns a "0 null" value. however it doesn't overwrite the old data.

Comment: Where is `$last_item` defined in your code? At what point are you reading the JSON file to get the current values so you can update them?

Comment: Well, yes, you're just writing to a file, not even in APPEND mode. That will always replace the file's contents. You'll in fact have to *read* the current contents, decode them, append to the array, encode the array and then write back to the file. Which will all be prone to race conditions, so you'll have to care for properly *locking* the file as well.

Comment: $last_item isn't being defined if ur asking where it's being defined (since this is all the code I have.) and to answer the other one: I guess that was the mistake I was making. so I'll have to work that out aswell now, any chance you could make it an answer so I can upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of `file_put_contents` is to replace the file. According to the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php), "the existing file is overwritten, unless the FILE_APPEND flag is set."

However, as @deceze pointed out, you don't actually want to append to your JSON file because it won't be valid JSON. You'll need to read in your existing JSON file, update it and then overwrite. You'll also need to add your objects to a top level array like this:

```
{
    "exercises": []
}
```

Comment: I made a little change to my Json, don't know if it's worth editing my post since that wasn't the original one. but now it throws me a "0 null" value.

Comment: If it's an unrelated problem, I think you should create a new question. Otherwise, edit your question.

Comment: No I mean, it is related, but it causes a new problem, and to be honest I think I am still missing stuff out... but I guess my post got downvoted anyway, so why not give it a go

Comment: The problem is, you can't just `FILE_APPEND` to a JSON file, it will make it invalid JSON.

Comment: @Userwithnoname You changed a lot of stuff at once in the new edit. I suggest going back to the old version and testing after each change. That will make it easier to figure out which change caused your error.

Comment: @mouche oke, i'll give it a try, and another question... just to clarify: the code u provided "exercises" is refering to "exerciseWord"?

Comment: @Userwithnoname No, it's a new array I created as an example. Since you want multiple of that whole data structure in the JSON file you posted, you'll need to put them into an array.